# Remove ¶ from string with php

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to remove the ¶ paragraph mark from a string.
I've already tried strip_tags and preg_replace, but its not working. The string is located in a mysql record. I've tried removing it before I save it in database and before displaying it but nothing seems to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Output the string with ¶ please.

Comment: How did it get in there in the first place?

Comment: What is the input character set of the string?

Answer (score 5):

Show your real string with ¶ because this works just great:

```
<?php

$string = 'Hi¶ this is a string with a paragraph¶';
$string = str_replace( "¶", "", $string );
echo $string;

?>
```

Output

```
Hi this is a string with a paragraph
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried that. If I echo the string its ok but ¶ is still in the database record and the slideshow (agile carousel) I am using to display the string does not display it, unless I remove it directly from mysql.

Comment: Well, if you don't want it inside db then remove it directly or find out, why it's there and stop putting it inside the db.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$mystring = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $mystring);
```

Removes the white spacing from the string